# Google fonts with Ionic framework

Tags: ionic-framework, google-font-api

I've made an app based on ionic framework, I'm using for fonts '[Cairo](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Cairo)' from google fonts.
The font is working fine when I use browser for testing, but when it come to the emulator it shows like square.
ps: I've download the font and modified the css file with new path and still not working.

This is the CSS file:

```css
/* arabic */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Changa';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Changa'), local('Changa-Regular'), url(changa/kJoVtULHl2iZq_3MNTQVo3-_kf6ByYO6CLYdB4HQE-Y.woff2) format('woff2');
  /*unicode-range: U+0600-06FF, U+200C-200E, U+2010-2011, U+FB50-FDFF, U+FE80-FEFC;*/
}
/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Changa';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Changa'), local('Changa-Regular'), url(changa/eZ-9bnVvsIhiJdRpRkxJ4X-_kf6ByYO6CLYdB4HQE-Y.woff2) format('woff2');
  /*unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+1E00-1EFF, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;*/
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Changa';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Changa'), local('Changa-Regular'), url(changa/u5aigp7vZoG41r3MEe43QuvvDin1pK8aKteLpeZ5c0A.woff2) format('woff2');
  /*unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215;*/
}
```

And This is the full path:
[image]

Comment: Please take a look at this link https://chriztalk.com/ionic-2-font-awesome/

Comment: please add your css code. Where ve you saved the fonts?

Comment: @Vanojx1 thank you for your response, I've added the CSS file and image for the path.

Comment: @digit I'm using Ionic 1